# Prevent promoted tweets on Twitter

Tags: twitter, feeds, tweet

I get "Promoted" tweets all the time on my Twitter feed and the majority of the time, they are just a nuisance as I've specifically selected accounts to follow and I feel like they are infringing on my feed on stuff I actually want to read. I know some have a "Dismiss" option but not all. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Are you viewing in the browser or through an app?

Comment: In a browser, Chrome specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the [Stylebot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylebot/oiaejidbmkiecgbjeifoejpgmdaleoha?hl=en) plugin in Chrome to load some custom CSS for the Twitter site.

```
.promoted-tweet {
    display: none;
}
```

That little bit of CSS will make all the promoted Tweets invisible.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't like the promoted tweets then use an app instead. I use Tweetbot on iOS and Mac. It allows you to filter in many ways, including blocking promoted tweets. I block any number of things on Twitter and it makes the whole experience so much cleaner.